# Make a bonus last for 3 seconds in XNA

Tags: c#, timer, xna

I'am building a game in XNA, and I'am very new to XNA as well, but I got to start somewhere. Almost everything in my games works perfect. It is an topview racing game. The only problem is that I want to last the bonuses, that I pickup from the map last for a given time, like 3 seconds, I know that I need to use a timer, but I don't know how I should use it.

this is a part of code, I use when the car collides with a tile of my map:

```
 if (map[x][y] == 0)
        {
            if (speedBonus)
            {
                car.speed = 450;
            }
            else
            {
                car.speed = 200;
            }
```

I hope one of you guys can help me with this problem, because I have spent like 2 hours fixing it, but my code didn't help me out. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, I fixed my code this way:

With 2 variables on top:

```
float timer = 3;
const float TIMER = 3;
```

And in the update:

```
if (map[x][y] == 0)
        {
            if (speedBonus)
            {
                float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
                timer -= elapsed;

                car.speed = 450;

                if (timer <= 0)
                {
                    speedBonus = false;
                    timer = TIMER;   //Reset Timer
                }
            }
            else
            {
                car.speed = 200;
            }
```

it now works like a charm, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to record the time the bonus was picked up, which you can save into a DateTime object.  Then, during each iteration of your main loop, check to see if the TimeSpan is greater than 3 seconds.  If so, remove the bonus.